# The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE) in Windows Server 2016 and Office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I have a C# application in server 2016. It was running  fine before installing Office 365.

We recently installed Office 365 in the server. Application is failing with an exception

> "The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.OpenText(String Filename, Object Origin, Object StartRow, Object DataType, XlTextQualifier TextQualifier, Object ConsecutiveDelimiter, Object Tab, Object Semicolon, Object Comma, Object Space, Object Other, Object OtherChar, Object FieldInfo, Object TextVisualLayout, Object DecimalSeparator, Object ThousandsSeparator, Object TrailingMinusNumbers, Object Local).

I have code like below to generate the XLS file...

```
object[,] myArray = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}
                    , {7, 1}, {8, 1},{9, 1},{10, 1},{11, 1},{12, 1},{13, 1},{14, 1},{15, 1},{16, 1},{17, 1},{18, 1},{19, 1}};
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbooks newWorkBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook m_wB;
        object m_objOpt = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        newWorkBooks.OpenText(textFilePath, 437, 1, Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
           false, false, false, false, false, true, "|", FieldInfo: myArray);
        m_wB = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook;

        Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)m_wB.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        string[] getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetParent(outputPath).ToString(), sheetName + "_*.txt");

        FormatSheet(workSheet, excelApp, sheetName, (getFiles.Length == 0));


        m_wB.SaveAs(outputPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, m_objOpt, m_objOpt,
             m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
        m_wB.Close(false, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
        newWorkBooks.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();
```

It is failing at `OpenTextFile()`.

Any suggestions...

Comment: This is probably better suited for StackOverflow.  Also make sure you tag it with the language you are using.

Comment: From what I have read, it sounds like a firewall issue, try turning off the software firewall or place an acception in the firewall software allowing the Excel program through. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am generating the report in the server it self. if the file is generating in the server itself I don't think there is a firewall issue.